# Can an $n \times n$ matrix multiply by a $1 \times n$ vector in less than $n^2$?

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

I am working through an algorithm found in [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0885064X84710211/1-s2.0-S0885064X84710211-main.pdf?_tid=a0dde918-9467-11e6-8f55-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1476708528_d05b7f94c343ee4ae1ede0e43659bc83) paper, which is used to multiply an $n \times n$  Vandermonde matrix by a $1 \times n$  vector.

To my understanding, trying to do this kind of multiplication normally should require $n^2$ multiplies. So for this algorithm to be worth anything, I would assume it to take less than that here.

The result of the 'preprocessing' stage of Algorithm 2.1 outputs a representation of the $n \times n$  transposed Vandermonde matrix as

> $V^T = J \cdot D_{\phi} \cdot F \cdot A_{\phi}^{-1} \cdot F^{*} \cdot D_{\phi}^{-1} \cdot V(t)^{-1} \cdot D_{fg}$

Which involves making some calcualtions in the preprocessing to get those terms.

My belief was that there would be some way this representation could multiply by a $1 \times n$  vector more quickly than an $n \times n$  matrix, but I don't quite understand how this can be the case. It seems that trying to do less multiplications than that would somehow miss certain combinations and thus lose information. Since this product set of matrices multiplies together to get a $n \times n$  matrix instead of something smaller, how is it that this representation would be any more useful than the normal representation?

Comment: If you have actual code that you're working with, this question *may* be suited to [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is possible at least when the Vandermonde matrix is the DFT (=Discrete Fourier Transform) matrix. That gets to IIRC $O(n\log n)$ by using FFT. May be it's a similar idea? Hard to say without looking more closely.

Comment: This question is certainly on topic here, since it has to do with numerical linear algebra.

Comment: I think the key fact is that each factor in that expression for $V^T$ can be multiplied by a vector very efficiently. (Crucially, the FFT can be used for products involving $F$.) Hence, we can multiply $V^T$ by a vector very efficiently.

Comment: Looking at the part just below the algorithm it says that the process can be completed in i(n) + e(n) + O(n^2). Since it wouldn't be very useful if O(n^2) was the complexity, I think that must be the preprocessing complexity, which would make the application O(n), correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your question is actually suited to Math.SE, but nonetheless:

It is not true that there are $n^2$ *independent* terms in the matrix in the informational sense. All terms are determined from just $n$ of them (because it's a Vandermonde matrix), and so this information can be used to speed up calculation.

Comment: Im sorry if this is the wrong place for this, it's a math paper, so I didn't know where else it might fit.

Comment: @Zephyr - Don't mind that; people seem to think the question belongs here. I just wasn't sure personally. I might be able to give you a better answer if you elaborate on what it is you want to understand better. I think I've explained in principle why it doesn't need to take $n^2$ operations, and as for the implementation of the algorithm, well that will be included or referenced by the paper.